# FFT performance figures

Tags: algorithm, performance, gpu, fft, cpu

I am wondering what time performance one can achieve nowadays to compute 2D FFTs. Just an order of magnitude, for 1K x 1K or 2K x 2K images.

Links or personal experience are welcome.

Comment: AFAIR, about 5 ms for 1Kx1K image using FFTW library in single-thread mode on i5-4670

Comment: I concur with @MBo's ballpark figure, although note that it depends somewhat on whether you're using single/double precision, and whether it's real-to-complex or complex-to-complex, and in-place or not. Also note that if you're doing this on multiple cores then cache/memory pressure can be pretty nasty with the FFT's somewhat pseudo-random access pattern.

Comment: @PaulR: yes, it depends on numerous factors. This is why I just asked for an order of magnitude.

Comment: Why don't you measure?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: because of the cost. I am in a preliminary feasibility study, and no time is allocated to perform benchmarking. Life's hard, you know.

Answer (score 2):

Rerun simple test for reference:

FFTW library 3.3.5 (2016 year). I've used precompiled dll's, they exploit `SSE`, but I am not sure about `AVX`.
Windows 7 32 bit. Intel i5-4670 (Haswell 4 cores)

Single precision, real-to complex out-of place 2D transform (using `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d`).

```
1024 x 1024: 
        Single thread: 5 ms per iteration
        Two threads: 3.8 ms per iteration
        Four threads: 2.4 ms per iteration

2048 x 2048: 
        Single thread: 28 ms per iteration
        Two threads: 16 ms per iteration
        Four threads: 12 ms per iteration
```

Double precision, real-to complex out-of place 2D transform (using `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d`).

```
1024 x 1024: 
     Single thread: 7 ms per iteration
     Four threads: 3 ms per iteration
```